# Ignorar archivos sin restaurar cambios Git

Tags: git

¿Como puedo ignorar los archivos que tengo cuando le doy el `git status`?

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   .vs/InformesBI/v14/.suo
        modified:   .vs/config/applicationhost.config
        modified:   Admin/Admin.csproj
        modified:   Admin/Admin.csproj.user
        modified:   Admin/Content/bootstrap-theme.css
        modified:   Admin/Content/bootstrap.css
        modified:   Admin/Content/bootstrap.min.css
        modified:   Admin/Scripts/_references.js
        modified:   Admin/Scripts/bootstrap.js
        modified:   Admin/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js
```

Baje el código de un repositorio pero me daban error en la referencias así que tuve que hacer un `update-package -reinstall` a las dependencias para que se me pudiera correr la app pero no quiero que me aparezcan ahí.

No se si también afecte en los archivos untracked

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .vs/InformesBI/FileContentIndex/
        .vs/InformesBI/config/
        .vs/InformesBI/v14/suo84E8.tmp
        .vs/InformesBI/v17/
        Admin/bin/Admin.dll
        Admin/bin/Admin.dll.config
        Admin/bin/Admin.pdb
```

Comment: Podrías reemplazar la imagen por texto en la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los archivos que están *untracked* a los que no les quieras prestar atención los puedes agregar al archivo `.gitignore` (en el árbol de trabajo, por lo que el archivo puede ser agregado) o a `.git/info/exclude` (que no está en el árbol de trabajo y por lo tanto no puede ser agregado, es algo local de ese repositorio).

Cuando quieres ignorar cambios sobre archivos a los que ya git les está haciendo tracking, tienes que correr esto:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged un-archivo
```

Eso va a hacer que si hay cambios locales en los archivos, git no los considere. Este tipo de comportamiento, en realidad, nunca lo he probado cuando hay cambios en dichos archivos al hacer un `git pull` or `merge`, para que lo tengas en consideración.

Comment: Gracias, lo probare y te confirmo como respuesta si me ayudo.